# iOS CoreBluetooth How to differ from read response and notifying packet?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

We have a battery characteristic on our peripheral device that is **both readable and notifying**.

In Android, it's easy, there's a callback function for read responses (`onCharacteristicRead`) and one for notifying packets (`onCharacteristicChanged`).

But in iOS, there's only one callback function for both reads and notifications (`didUpdateValueForCharacteristic`) and we can't seem to find a way to identify which peripheral action is happening (read or notify).

Is there a way to know if we're getting a read response or a notification?

*Note that for characteritics that are only readable or notifying, we don't have any problem and the code works like a charm.*

Comment: Firstly, why do you care?  You got a new value, so just handle it as required.  But to answer your question, there is no way to know for sure. You could set a flag when you issue a read and then check it when you get an updated value; if it is set then *it is likley* that this is an update in response to your read but you can't know for sure.

Comment: I don't really care... I'm just curious. My apps works fine either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to identify the read response and the notification because they comes from the same callback without identifier.

If you want to differentiate them for special case, you may need to use two protocol (one for read, another for notify) in the firmware side. So you can differentiate them in the App with your protocol. Generally, we don't differentiate them.